# bootstrap framework for SharePoint 2013

Tags: branding

Is there any body who tried to use bootstrap framework for SharePoint 2013?
i want to use this framework for our company TeamSite branding but i got an error

**"The user interface version can not be determined"**

Comment: What is the version of your sharepoint master page?

Comment: you mean version of bootstrap's masterpage? i've downloaded this version B3-SharePoint2013-BetaV1.0.1 and use it for sharepoint 2013